# Search and replace within a text field to remove part of field

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mySQL with a text field that has a variety of text and included in that text is social security numbers in this format  SS# 111-22-3333   There is about 40,000 records in the table.  I want to be able to search the field and remove the social security number from the field leaving the rest of the text intact.   I've searched and not found an example of how to do that.

Comment: Can you provide an example (DUMMY OUT THE SSN!) so we can see what the transformation will actually need to look like?

Comment: Unless the SSN appears at the same location within each record, this isn't really a task that MySQL can perform natively.  You can achieve it with a UDF, but it's probably something you're better off doing in your application layer...

Comment: @eggyal is right on the money.  MySQL can't really handle this unless the SSNs appear in the exact same position within the field on every record.

Comment: here is an example of the data - this is all in one field within the table.

Bob H. Test, SS# 111-22-333
Born: 1-1-1900, Mytown, NY.
Died: 9-9-2002, MyTown, NY.
Husband of: Julia Smith Jones
Son of: John S. and Rebecca J. New Test
Burial: St. Toms Cemetery, MyTown, NY.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native function to that. You might use a User Defined Function - take a look here:
https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp

You could also consider using an ETL framework for that (such as Clvoer ETL Framework - http://www.cloveretl.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that the social security number is starting with "SS#".  I think you can do what you want with this:

```
update t
    set text = insert(text, instr(text, 'SS#'), 15, '')
    where field regexp 'SS#[0-9]0-9][0-9]-[0-9]0-9]-[0-9]0-9][0-9]';
```

That is, find the rows that contain a social security number.  Then find the beginning of the pattern and replace the next 15 characters with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If *all* SSNs in the text are preceded by `SS#` and a space, *and* they're all in 999-99-9999 format, you can use the [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function to get the position of `SS#` and then do the rest with `SUBSTRING`:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET text =
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING(text, 1, LOCATE('SS# ', text) - 1),
    SUBSTRING(text, LOCATE('SS# ', text) + 15)
  )
WHERE text LIKE '%SS# %'
```

Using the sample you just posted, the query will turn this...

```
Bob H. Test, SS# 111-22-3333 Born: 1-1-1900, Mytown, NY. Died: 9-9-2002, ...
```

... into this:

```
Bob H. Test,  Born: 1-1-1900, Mytown, NY. Died: 9-9-2002, ...
```

Comment: I'm going to try this on a backup of my data - I'll let you know if it solves my problem... thanks!